# Symfony 3 .htaccess mod_alias fallback explanation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I looked at the Symfony 3 `.htaccess` file and found this:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Could someone explain me the usefulness of this RedirectMatch directive cause I can't seem to get it. If mod_rewrite isn't enabled and I will request `http://localhost/myproject/web/` it won't even be triggered cause `^/$` matches against the `URL-path` which is `/myproject/web/` in this case...

Is this fallback designed to be useful only in production when the application resides inside of the document root and not in a subdirectory of it as it usually does when developing locally?

How does it work in detail?